# Fill values beyond the mask

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, masking

I have some .tif raster and .shp mask, and I need to fill values in the raster, which are beyond the mask, with -999. How can I do this using QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the **Clipper** tool which you can find from the menubar:

   ```
   Raster > Extraction > Clipper
   ```

   And set the parameters using the mask layer:

   [image: Clipper]

   This should create an output of your raster within the mask layer and everything outside the mask layer should have a value of `0`.

---

2. Use the **Raster Calculator** on the output:

   ```
   Raster > Raster Calculator
   ```

   And use an expression like the following to change all `0` values (i.e. values outside your masked raster) to `-999` whilst all values inside remain the same:

   ```
   (("Raster@1" != 0) * "Raster@1") + (("Raster@1" = 0) * -999)
   ```